# Are ProfileBase, HttpContext.Request.AnonymousId available as a part of the ASP.Net Core 2.x suite? If so how do I access them.

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, migration, httpcontext, asp.net-core-2.1

I am currently trying to migrate ASP.Net MVC API 4.6.2 app to ASP.Net Core 2.1.

```
     private static string GetSessionId()
    {
        // Get from the session state, most reliable, but not likely available
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID))
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
        }

        // if the application has enabled anonymous tracking, then this is also reliable
        // (note: this requires <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" /> in the web.onfig.
        if (HttpContext.Current.Profile.IsAnonymous &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID))
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID;
        }

        // last resort, we track this ourselves.
        var telemetryId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[TelemetryKey] != null
            ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[TelemetryKey].Value
            : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var telemetryCookie = new HttpCookie(TelemetryKey, telemetryId) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) };
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(telemetryCookie);

        return telemetryId;
    }
```

Now in the .Net Core version, I am unable to find equivalents. And yes, I have registered the IHttpContextAccessor through ConfigureServices() and am able to access it in this service class. But, the current HttpContext does not seem to have all the properties that the Sytem.Web.Http namespace offered.

Are there any alternatives to check if the user is anoanymous?

```
    (HttpContext.Current.Profile.IsAnonymous && 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID))
```

Also, it'd be great if any suggestions could be made about retaining Http calls in a .Net standard class library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the AnonymousId has been discontinued in .Net Core due to its negligible usage and needs to implemented through a custom middle-ware if necessary. 
While writing the custom middle-ware for achieving the same I discovered that somebody had already walked this path before and had written a custom middle-ware which can be found at the following link: https://github.com/aleripe/AnonymousId

It saved a lot of my time and hope it does yours too if you were looking for something of this sort.

FYI: I couldn't find much about the ProfileBase library in .Net Core.